# How to sort by second column in KQL regardless of column name

Tags: kql, monitor, azure-log-analytics

I used `pivot` in KQL, now I have dynamically named columns and I would like to sort by the second one.

The table looks like this

| Product | 11.2023 | 10.2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 80 | 50 |
| Name 2 | 24 | 71 |
| Name 3 | 33 | 60 |

I want to sort by the "11.2023" column (second column overall), but this column is not always the same, however, I want to always use the same query.

I thought something like

```
T
| order by 1 desc
```

or

```
T
| sort by 1 desc
```

would work but it just doesn't sort.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [sort operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sort-operator),

> It's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation that we can sort by ordinal position if we use query like `sort by 1 desc`. So, it's not possible with the above query.

It will give the same table result with your table.

**These are my observations when I tried various methods:**

I tried the following method where first I have stored the second column name in a variable using `getschema`.

```
let a = datatable(Product:string, ['11.2023']:int, ['10.2023']:int)
[
    "Name 3",80,50,
    "a",24,71,
    "Name 2",33,60
];
let s =a | getschema;
let b= toscalar(s
| extend col= iif(ColumnOrdinal==0,ColumnName,'')
| summarize max(col)
);
a
| order by column_ifexists(b,'') desc;
```

But later when I tried to order by that variable, I got an error saying `column_ifexists(): argument #1 must be string literal`.

[image]

The `column_ifexists()` methods first argument should be only a string literal but here the string variable `b` was calculated from another expression.

I have tried to build a KQL string query and tried to execute that, but currently KQL doesn't have any equivalent functions like `exec()` of SQL.

So, currently it might not be possible to achieve your requirement. You can raise your idea as a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/a952add5-eb24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0).

Comment: Thank you for your efforts in researching and explaining. It's unfortunate to hear that this might not be possible. I think I will implement sorting in the code that consumes the query result for now.